How to Clear local-address and remote-address in MikroTik PPP Secret Using Laravel API
I'm using the evilfreelancer/routeros-api-php package to interact with a MikroTik router via API. After creating a PPP secret user with a static IP, I want to clear or unset the local-address and remote-address fields.
Here's what I've tried:

Setting local-address and remote-address to null:

$query->equal('local-address', null);
$query->equal('remote-address', null);


Setting them to an empty string:

$query->equal('local-address', '');
$query->equal('remote-address', '');

Both approaches result in an error:
array (
    'after' => array (
        'message' => 'invalid value for argument address',
    ),
)

It seems like null and "" are not acceptable values for these fields. In the MikroTik terminal, I can clear them, but I'm looking for a way to accomplish this via the API.
Has anyone successfully cleared these fields using laravel? Is there a way to "unset" these values via the API, or is setting them to 0.0.0.0 the only workaround?
